# "have been" or "had been"?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Suppose you were a pilot for an airline for five years. But then you left the job. So if someone asks you "do you know how to fly a plane?" what would your answer be?

> a) I have been a pilot for five years so i think i know how to fly a plane

or

> b) I had been a pilot for five years so i think i know how to fly a plane.

As far as I know it should be "b" because he is not a pilot anymore and if I say "I have been a pilot", it can also mean that he is still a pilot. But I don't wanna say that because he isn't.

Answer (score 2):

(a) would be used if the speaker was *still* a pilot.

If the speaker is no longer a pilot, I agree with Mick the expression should be "I was a pilot for five years..."

(b) by itself sounds incomplete.  It is setting up a record of when something happened, so the speaker should finish by saying what happened.  "I had been a pilot for 5 years *when I decided to quit my job.*"  "I had been a pilot for five years *before my son was born*." etc.

Note that leaving a specific job does not make someone cease to be a pilot - they are still a pilot so long as they have a pilot's license, even if they are not exercising that as their trade.

"I have been a pilot since the 60's, but I don't currently work for an airline."

Comment: So it means if i still have a pilot license then i would say "i have been a pilot for five years and if i don't have a license then "i was a pilot for five years". Sorry for bothering but i learnt that if something is happening for longer duration you usually use have/has+been or had+been but i am not so sure about using "was" for something which is happening for a long time and if it is used can you please provide a link to a website which shows more examples of it.

Comment: The two examples you state are correct.  Use of "have been" vs. "was" is not about duration, it is about whether the action ended or is ongoing.  Sorry I don't have any specific websites to point you to,

Answer (score 1):

In this case the imperfect *was* would possibly be a better fit.

*I was a pilot for five years...*